# Replace <div class="something"> followed by </p>

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace strings like `<div></p>` with `<div>` and `<div foo="bar"></p>` with `<div foo="bar">`

How can I do that using preg_replace?
I don't know very much about Regex, but I was trying something like:

```
preg_replace( '/(<div.*><\/p)/', '$1', $content);
```

Comment: ...Preempting the _"use a proper HTML parser"_ comments, that's invalid HTML and probably won't parse...

Comment: It's related to a Wordpress bug with wpautop and shortcodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an expression like `[^>]*` to match everything up to but not including the next `>` and capture it in `$1` with a `()` group, if anything is present at all (since `*` matches zero or more of the preceding expression)

That makes your expression look like:

```
/<div([^>]*)><\/p>/
```

Your replacement pattern is then `<div$1>` using that backreference which now contains *everything* else between `<div` and `>` including its whitespace.

And it works accordingly:

```
$s1 = '<div></p>';
$s2 = '<div foo="bar"></p>';

echo preg_replace('/<div([^>]*)><\/p>/', '<div$1>', $s1);
// <div>
echo preg_replace('/<div([^>]*)><\/p>/', '<div$1>', $s2);
// <div foo="bar">
```

And another method more similar to what you were attempting is to capture the `<div>` structure as a unit into `$1` with `(<div[^>]*>)`, which then becomes the whole replacement expression:

```
echo preg_replace('/(<div[^>]*>)<\/p>/', '$1', $s1);
// <div>
echo preg_replace('/(<div[^>]*>)<\/p>/', '$1', $s2);
// <div foo="bar">
```